# how to write Linq Query for following ouput

Tags: c#, linq

```
var Shopping= new[] 
{
    new { Code = 1, Name = "Store 1", Type="Test1", Value="Bean"},
    new { Code = 1, Name = "Store 1", Type="Test2", Value="Broccoli"},
    new { Code = 2, Name = "Store 1", Type="Test1", Value="Beetroot"},
    new { Code = 11, Name = "Store 2", Type="Test1", Value="Apple"},
    new { Code = 11, Name = "Store 2" , Type="Test2", Value="Mango"}    
};
```

Output:

*Store 1*

```
  Code Test1 Test2
   1   Bean  Broccoli
   2         Beetroot
```

*Store 2*

```
  Code Test1 Test2
   11  Apple Mango
```

How can I make query in Linq C# for following output?

Comment: Hi Rochelle, have you tried anything?

Comment: Smells like homework...

Comment: try `Shopping.GroupBy(x => x.Name)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get what you are trying to achieve you need to do 2 `GroupBy`s. First for the `Name` (store) and then within that to group by the `Code`. Eventually to get the different fields you want out of the different rows it is called pivoting.

```
var result = Shopping.GroupBy(item => item.Name)
        .Select(group => new
        {
            Store = group.Key,
            Items = group.GroupBy(item => item.Code)
                         .Select(innerGroup => new
                         {
                             Code = innerGroup.Key,
                             //This is the pivoting part - I create a "column" and collect under it all the values for that type
                             Test1 = innerGroup.Where(item => item.Type == "Test1").Select(item => item.Value).ToList(),
                             Test2 = innerGroup.Where(item => item.Type == "Test2").Select(item => item.Value).ToList(),
                         }).ToList()
        }).ToList();
```

1. *Note: you have an mistake in your data - the record with the `Value`
   of `Beetroot` should have a `Type` of `Test2` and not `Test1` in
   order to get it like you wanted.*
2. I've added all the `ToLists()` just to ease when debugging - they are not needed.

---

You can also convert it into a dictionary:

```
var stores = Shopping.GroupBy(item => item.Name)
        .Select(group => new
        {
            Store = group.Key,
            Items = group.GroupBy(item => item.Code)
                         .Select(innerGroup => new
                         {
                             Code = innerGroup.Key,
                             Test1 = innerGroup.Where(item => item.Type == "Test1").Select(item => item.Value).ToList(),
                             Test2 = innerGroup.Where(item => item.Type == "Test2").Select(item => item.Value).ToList(),
                         }).ToDictionary(key => key.Code, value => value)
        }).ToDictionary(key => key.Store, value => value.Items);
```

And then can access it by writing: `result["Store 1"][1].Test1`

Comment: @Rochelle - Did it help you?

Comment: Yes ,somehow,but I dont want to get Test1 and test2 in list form.how can I get without list.

Comment: @Rochelle - I didn't really understand how you want your output then. Please explain.. because by what you posted this is what you wanted

Comment: I remove .ToList() from code but no value is coming for Test1 and Test2.

Comment: @Rochelle - it does. It is because it is a deferred executed function. In debug you can see "Results view   Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable"

Comment: @Rochelle - and for what you said above - `Test1` and `Test2` are lists

Comment: Test1 = innerGroup.Where(item => item.Type == "Test1").Select(item => item.Value).ToList(),
                             Test2 = innerGroup.Where(item => item.Type == "Test2").Select(item => item.Value).ToList(),   I want this should output like Test1="Bean " and Test2="Broccoli" not in form of list

Comment: @Rochelle - but by your example you wanted to group them by the Code. If that is the case then what to do with the multiple values? Do you want to concatenate all those strings into one?

Comment: I want output like this   Code Test1 Test2
                                       1   Bean  Broccoli
                                       2  Beetroot   , I modified query but not getting following output

Comment: @Rochelle - like how? The Test1 will be one string containing all those strings inside it?

Comment: var result2 = _shopping
.GroupBy(g => new { Code = g.Code, Name = g.Name })
.Where(grp => Convert.ToString(grp.Key.Name) == "Store 1")
.Select(innerGroup => new {
  Code = innerGroup.Key,                                          
  Test1 = innerGroup.Where(item => item.Type1 == "Test1").Select(item => new { item.Value }),  Test2 = innerGroup.Where(item => item.Type1 == "Test2").Select(item => new { item.Value }),                                         }).ToList();

Comment: Output are not directly display Code=1 ,Test1=Bean,Test2=Broccoli

Comment: @Rochelle - then use a `FirstOrDefault()?.Value` instead of `Select(.......).ToList()`